# r - Use elements of a vector of characters as patterns for grep

Tags: r, regex, vector

I have a vector of hours and minutes:

`Date=format( seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 05:55:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 21:55:00"), by = "15 min"), "%H:%M:%S", tz="Europe/Rome")`

I would like to use the elements of that vector (i.e. `Date[4]`) as part of a grep pattern:

```
grep("2016-01-.. Date[4]", df$first)
```

I'm actually trying to do something like this:

```
grep("2016-01-.. 09:25:00", df$first)
```

What am i missing?

Comment: `grep` isn't vectorized over patterns, so you can (a) use a loop (`for`, `sapply`, etc.), (b) use `vectorize` on it to create vectorized version, (c) use a similar function like `stringr::str_detect()` which is vectorized over patterns. In all cases, use `paste0` to build a vector of patterns, `paste0("2016-01-.. ", Date)`

Comment: I'm pretty new to r so bear with me. Using a for loop isn't helping: `for(i in c(1:10)){
 c<-grep("Date[i]", df$fist)
}` I can't understand why it's not treating `Date[i]` as a normal string, as it is.

Comment: When you put `Date[i]` in quotes, *the string is then `"Date[i]"`*. To use the string stored *in the variable `Date[i]`*, don't use quotes: `for(i in c(1:10)){ c<-grep(Date[i], df$fist) }`. (One more suggestion: don't use `c` as a variable name. Because `c()` is the most common function it can be confusing.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can loop through your list. Extending it to your `grep` statement should be simple

```
for (i in 1:length(Date)){
  print(Date[i])
}

[1] "14:55:00"
[1] "15:10:00"
[1] "15:25:00"
[1] "15:40:00"
...
```